# &amp in url using window.location

Tags: javascript, twig, window.location

I try to use `window.location` with parameters within twig and javascript.

```
function() {
   window.location = '{{ redirect_uri ~ '?status=cancel&review_id=' ~ review_id }}';
});
```

The problem is that the new url has `&amp` instead of `&`.

Example:

> http://local.dev/app_dev.php/admin?status=cancel&review_id=67

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [raw](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html) filter, as example:

```
function() {
   window.location = '{{ (redirect_uri ~ '?status=cancel&review_id=' ~ review_id)|raw }}';
});
```

[Here](https://twigfiddle.com/qnxtkf) a working example

Comment: Are you sure it's `raw`, isn't there a "JS string literal" filter?